# How to insert three images using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**This is my view file**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Package Image(Large) </label>
      <?= form_input(array('type'=>'file','id'=>'pkg_img','name'=>'pkg_img','class'=>'form-control','multiple'=>'')); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Package Image(Mediam)</label>
    <?= form_input(array('type'=>'file','id'=>'pkg_img_md','name'=>'pkg_img_md','class'=>'form-control','multiple'=>'')); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Package Image(Small)</label>
    <?= form_input(array('type'=>'file','id'=>'pkg_img_sm','name'=>'pkg_img_sm','class'=>'form-control','multiple'=>'')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i want to insert 3 images one by one  using codeigniter

Comment: And what is not working yet? The code already shows some form elements for two images

Comment: my question is how to insert 3 images without an array

Comment: I cannot see an array in your code, so where is the problem?

Comment: sir this is my only view page if you know how to insert two or three images without an array using codeigniter please write the coed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be rude, but I don't get the question yet. You already wrote code for three input fields for an image, without involving any array access, and I don't get what you mean by "insert three images". Do you want to output the images themselves? Then write `<img>` tags. Do you want to upload them to your server? Then you should share you controller code. Is there some completely other problem? Then state it clearly, please

Answer (score 0):

Use Html helper class

```
 $image_properties = array(
        'src'   => 'images/picture.jpg',
        'alt'   => 'Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time',
        'class' => 'post_images',
        'width' => '200',
        'height'=> '200',
        'title' => 'That was quite a night',
        'rel'   => 'lightbox'
);

img($image_properties);
// <img src="http://url/index.php/images/picture.jpg" alt="Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time" class="post_images" width="200" height="200" title="That was quite a night" rel="lightbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want to resize the same image differently (small, medium) sizes you can use the following code. If that is not what you want to accomplish than you can modify it to your liking:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('form');

        echo form_open_multipart('/test/upload_image/');
        echo form_upload('userfile');
        echo form_submit(array('name' => 'add_file', 'value' => 'Add File'));
    }

    public function upload_image() {

        if (!is_dir('./uploads/')) {
            mkdir('./uploads/', 0755);
        }

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            // handle this with flash messages & redirect
            exit($this->upload->display_errors());
        }

        $image = $this->upload->data();

        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config = array(); // reset config array

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '';

        $config_sm['new_image'] = "./uploads/{$image['raw_name']}_sm{$image['file_ext']}";
        $config_sm['width'] = 50;
        $config_sm['height'] = 50;

        $this->image_lib->initialize(array_merge($config, $config_sm));

        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $this->image_lib->clear();

        $config_md['new_image'] = "./uploads/{$image['raw_name']}_md{$image['file_ext']}";
        $config_md['width'] = 100;
        $config_md['height'] = 100;

        $this->image_lib->initialize(array_merge($config, $config_md));

        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $data = array(
            'pkg_img_sm' => $config_sm['new_image'],
            'pkg_img_md' => $config_md['new_image'],
            'pkg_img' => $image['full_path'],
        );

        print_r($data);

        //$this->db->insert('sometable', $data);
    }

}
```

Will generate an array that looks like:

```
Array ( [pkg_img_sm] => ./uploads/936174c69e709b4c6d7fb840c4094eba_sm.jpg [pkg_img_md] => ./uploads/936174c69e709b4c6d7fb840c4094eba_md.jpg [pkg_img] => C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/936174c69e709b4c6d7fb840c4094eba.jpg )
```